# Change id of foreign key object while add new object in EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm

I use EF as ORM, but I have problem with simple add object with foreign keys. I execute this code below to add new article to DB.

```
dataLayer = new CmsDataLayer();
var newArticle = new Article();
newArticle.Author = AuthorService.CurrentAuthor; //id =8
dataLayer.Articles.Insert(newArticle);
```

There is `CmsDataLayer.ICmsRepository` is repository pattern (simple CRUD operation)

```
class CmsDataLayer
{ 
    public ICmsRepository<Author> Authors = new MsSqlServerCmsRepository<Author>();
}
```

In method insert I do this

```
class MsSqlServerCmsRepository
{
    private DbSet<T> dataSet;

    public MsSqlServerCmsRepository()
    {
        dataSet = dataContext.Set<T>();
    }
    public void Insert(T entity)
    {
        this.dataSet.Add(entity);
        this.dataContext.SaveChanges(); //<-- 
    }
```

After this operation `newArticle.Author` gets new value of Author ID, before `SaveChanges()` entity it has Author with `id=8`, after Author has `id=14`.

I don't understand why EF change `AuthorId` after save operation, author with id=8 exists w DB?

Comment: EF is probably set to generate a new Id on creation, the last created entity probably had the Id of 13, so this one gets 14 as Id. If you want to update an Entity you should get it first. If you want to be the one specifying the Id (and not let EF increment the Id on every created Entity) you can specify that as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which data context the current author is loaded from in the author service, but I think you need to get it from the same context or attach it. Otherwise it will see it as a new object and insert it again. Alternatively, rather than setting the navigation property, you can leave it sert to null and set the key field .AuthorId instead.

Answer (score 0):

Is the author loaded from the same DB context (or attached to it)?
If not set author ID instead of navigation property.

Also save changes isn't supposed to be in the add method, it is supposed called before closing the DB context.

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply this modification:

```
public void InsertArticle(Article entity)
{
    entity.Author = this.dataContext.Authors.Find(entity.AuthorEntityIdPropertyName);
    this.dataSet.Add(entity);
    this.dataContext.SaveChanges(); //<-- 
}
```

Looking your code I think the AuthorService.CurrentAuthor is not tracked by the  MsSqlServerCmsRepository's dataContext. So that it will insert it wiht the next incremented id.